# Interacting with command line programs in Hopper disassembler (Mac OS 10.9)

Tags: debuggers, c++, hopper, mach-o

To test the debugging capabilities of Hopper, I wrote a simple C++ command line application, and tried to run it on the remote debugging server (with gdb). However, I learned after I failed to be able to interact with the application, from the author, that the Hopper server does not support CL apps currently. In other words, it seems the app has to have its own GUI.

Are there any workarounds for this? Specifically, is there a way I can write a standalone C++ Mach-O executable which has its own version of terminal built into it (without all the features, just an interpreter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Admirably, after just a few days after I sent in a request to include a feature to send input to command line applications, the sole developer of Hopper disassembler has included the feature. Notice the new 'application output' tab in the new Hopper disassembler 3.3.3:

[image]